# Wordpress page links not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

This is my website :- http://www.fourfront1602.com/
When i am clicking on any other page links or any link on the page , then again the home page appears , though the url in the address bar changes but no links open and again the home page appears .
Please help if anyone can !
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `page.php` and `single.php` file in your template directory?

Comment: yes i have both the files

Comment: Go in permalink setting and update the permalinks.

Comment: in permalink settings , it is set to "Post name" .

Comment: the urls are updating by clicking on a link because they are coming by the name of post or page as the permalink settings but the page is not updating , only home page opens on clicking any of the link

Comment: Yes I understand that, but sometimes htaccess get changed due to some plugins. Go in the permalinks in click on update button. It will rebuild your permalinks.

Comment: Actually each page on your site gives 404 error. There is problem with your htaccess I guess. http://gyazo.com/660baf92f302c4f69fa7ba46c8f39b6d check the screenshot.

Comment: so if there is an error in htaccess ,what can be the error and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

goto admin:
settings->permalinks

select custom structures : /%postname%/

Answer (score 1):

check your settings url.
dashboard->setting->general

there are feilds:
WordPress Address (URL):http://www.fourfront1602.com/
Site Address (URL):http://www.fourfront1602.com/

check this setting

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just visiting the Settings->Permalinks in the Dashboard did the trick!